# Пунктуация в предложении Л. Толстого

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Из "Анны Карениной":

> Алексей Александрович думал и говорил, что ни в какой год у него не было столько служебного дела, как в нынешний; но он не сознавал того, что он сам выдумывал себе в нынешнем году дела, что это было одно из средств не открывать того ящика, где лежали чувства к жене и семье и мысли о них(?) **и которые** делались тем страшнее, чем дольше они там лежали.

Не совсем понимаю, почему перед "и которые" нет запятой. "Которые" относится к "чувства", а не к "ящика".

Comment: Похоже на перенос ошибки из старых изданий. Запятая должна быть вместо "и" (перед "которые"), во всяком случае, так исправляют этот фрагмент при цитировании.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фраза необычна грамматикой, но в целом понимаема и пунктуационно верна. Запятой действительно не надо.
Объяснение через опечатку я не рассматриваю.

> "Которые" относится к "чувства", а не к "ящика".

Дело не в ящике, но вы на верном пути.
Здесь авторская не просто пунктуация, здесь "авторская" грамматика. У Толстого такие вещи встречаются.

Понимать надо так, что ***чувства и мысли*** — (какие?) ***к жене и семье и*** — (какие?) ***которые делались все страшнее***...

Автор делает однородными члены, которые в принципе очень трудно принять таковыми.

В таких случаях запятая проставляется или опускается по соображениям несколько иного плана, чем в общем правиле.

Вот смотрите, примеры из Розенталя (первый — тоже Толстой, кстати).

> Примечание. Следует различать случаи, когда одиночный союз *и* соединяет однородные придаточные части сложноподчинённого предложения (запятая перед *и* не ставится), и случаи, когда союз *и* соединяет два независимых предложения или однородные члены в главной части, между которыми находится придаточная часть (запятая перед *и* ставится). Ср.: *В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода* — не только предупреждается о наступлении заморозков, но и даются рекомендации насчет защиты овощей; *В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки, и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода* — делается только предупреждение о возможных заморозках, а вывод о необходимости принять соответствующие меры делает уже читатель.
>
> Однозначное толкование текста подсказывает такая пунктуация: *Хаджи-Мурат так задумался, что не заметил, как нагнул кувшин, и вода лилась из него* (Л. Т.) — при отсутствии запятой перед союзом *и* независимое предложение *вода лилась из него* стало бы соподчиненной придаточной частью (*...не заметил, как нагнул кувшин и как вода лилась из него*).
>
> Аналогичный пример: *Мысль о скорой разлуке со мной так поразила матушку, что она уронила ложку в кастрюльку, и слёзы потекли по её лицу* (П.) — при отсутствии запятой перед *и* текст имел бы такой вид: *...так поразила матушку, что... слёзы потекли по её лицу*.

Здесь два примера, в которых запятая необходима, чтобы различить две возможные трактовки — что чему подчиняется.

У нас ситуация иная: запятая как раз не требуется, поскольку имеет место  случай, подобный соподчинению, только вместо первого члена такого соподчинения стоит не придаточное, а обычное существительное в роли определения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139

Comment: То есть, присоединяемые через "и которые" чувства и мысли относятся не к жене, не к семье, а к чему-то неназванному третьему (и такие, которые) и определяются исключительно как "становящиеся всё страшнее" от лежания там же? Но дальше по тексту конкретизируются не эти третьи мысли с чувствами, а ранее упомянутые мысли о жене. Недоумение у меня вызывает не пунктуация, а присутствие союза "и" перед "которые", поскольку это радикально влияет на смысл и связность речи. "И+которые" обычно принадлежит схеме "которые А _и которые_ В".

Comment: @Alex_ander  *То есть, присоединяемые через "и которые" чувства и мысли относятся не к жене, не к семье, а к чему-то неназванному третьему* - простите,я не совсем понимаю, о чем вы говорите. И уж совсем не понимаю зачем. Грамматически фраза построена очень необычно, на грани допустимости, но, тем не менее, "которые" здесь союзное слово, которое однозначно соотносится с "мыслями" (и возможно, "чувствами").  Что до понимания фразы - ну да, тут могут быть варианты трактовки, Толстой не прост,  но на синтаксе и  пунктуации это никак не сказывается.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец *Объясните, пожалуйста, эту фразу из вашего ответа: вместо первого члена такого соподчинения стоит не придаточное, а обычное существительное в роли определения. И почему нельзя структуру предложения представить таким образом: где лежали чувства и мысли и где они (которые) делались страшнее?* ниже отвечаю.

Comment: Начну со второго вороса. По смыслу возможно, хотя и сомнительно. Разве чувства и мысли делались страшнее именно там, в ящике? Но, собственно, вопрос-то не в этом. Мы говорим о *грамматической* структуре фразы. А вот грамматика сопротивляется - у вас получается два сразу союзных слова к одному придаточному."где" и "которые".  Это даже для графа нашего перебор будет.

Comment: Что касается первого вопроса, то не очень понимаю, что тут надо объяснять. ну вот давайте "испортим" фразу ради моблюдения грамматики. ***...не открывать того ящика, где лежали чувства к жене и семье, о которых были мысли(,) и которые делались тем страшнее, чем дольше они там лежали***. Грамматически верно, хотя стилистически - очень неудачно. Но при попытке понять смысл тут же смысл возникает вопрос о запятой. Если без неё, о получается, что "страшнее" становились жена и семья. Запятая эту проблему решает.

Comment: Теперь восстанавливаем авторский текст, убирая мной сочиненное придаточное "о которых были мысли". Запятая по всей логике остается. Так понятнее?

Comment: А союз "и" что тогда делает после "убирания"?